# ElementaryOS Whan't too install dark theme

Tags: themes, elementary-project, elementary-website

i'm on Elementary OS and want to install Dark Theme , Somebody Can Help Me ? Thanks

Comment: What eOS version?

Comment: The developers are working on it for the next major release: https://github.com/orgs/elementary/projects/43

Comment: thanks for your answer , and yes is not full dark for moment may be in future in elementary os 6 ️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parts of Dark theme could be enabled via elementary-tweaks. Search the web, install it and enable it. It's not full Dark on Hera.